# On html, data in table form, how i click and print data on 2nd position using selenium web-driver java

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How i click link and print the data using selenium webdriver.
Here i want to click link Yahoo.com and want to print "Yahoo"
Also i want to print the data "Searched data of Yahoo"
Here link and printable data and links  are dynamically. So how i do these using selenium webdriver in Java Language

```
<table>
       <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span>
                            <a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                      <td>
                         <span>Searched data on Google</span>
                      </td>
                </tr>
               <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span>
                            <a href="www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a>
                        </span>
                    </td>
                      <td>
                         <span>Searched data on Yahoo</span>
                        </td>
                </tr>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this code:

```
void linkToClick(str linkName) {
    WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//a[contains(.,'" + linkName + "')]")); // finding link with desired name like yahoo or google
    WebElement data = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table//a[contains(.,'" + linkName + "')]/ancestor::td/following-sibling::td/span")); // finding text in the span next to provided link
    System.out.println(data.getText()); // printing text in span
    link.click(); // clicking link
}
```

Hope this is what u r looking for...

Comment: Hey @Vivek Singh linkname yahoo and google is not static link, here link and data changes dynamically

Comment: Means u dont know which link will be available there?

Comment: On my code or in the website
Link, link-name and data changes dynamically
Any think Link, link-name and data is not static
Only table structure is same, but link, link-name and data changes dynamically

Comment: do you need to click each link or a specific only? specific in a sense any row ?

Comment: I want to click second link yahoo and print the data "Searched data on Yahoo"

Comment: lets have a discussion over [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67696/question-27653422)

Comment: this is what my answer does. U need to pass linkName as Yahoo in the method, and it will search for any link under `a` tag in the table and click on it. Before clicking it will print the data in the following td i.e. `Searched data on Yahoo`.

Comment: well i need 20 reputation to chat

Comment: Ok...can u explain me your scenario in detail here.

Comment: i have anther account can we chat on through that account

Comment: hello i am chatting from your created room with the same question